# OAuthにおけるリダイレクトURIについて

Tags: oauth

現在OAuthについて勉強しているのですが、認可コードフローにおけるリダイレクトURIのメリットがよく分からず悩んでいます。
認可サーバではリダイレクトURIを把握しているので、直接認可コードをリダイレクトURIとして登録されている先に渡せば済む話ではないのでしょうか。
ユーザを経由することで、認可コードが露呈する可能性が高まっているような気がするのですが、このリダイレクトには何か意図があるのでしょうか。